# How can I populate partial view with results from my Controller (ASP.NET M V C)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

***Before you start reading guys please read comments in code carefully.***

I need to display unread emails for currently logged in user.

When user logs in to a system there will be notification that he has some unread emails and when user clicks on a email (that notification) there should be displayed real emails from database like this:

[image]

As much as I understand how this might work as a javascript absolutly beginner I guess I need to attach on click event which will call javascript method which will make an ajax call to my controller which will return some results (unread messages from database) to me.

Now I will post code of image you saw above:

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="GetAllUnreadEmails('@LogedUserId') class="dropdown-toggle           info-number" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="visibility:@visibility;">
 <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
   @if (LoggedInUser != null)
   {
     // HERE I AM SHOWING ICON LETTER AND NUMBER OF UNREAD that you saw on image above

     int unredEmails = EmailController.GetNumberOfUnreadEmails(LoggedInUser.Id);
     if (unredEmails > 0)
     {
        <span class="badge bg-orange" id="inboxunredEmails">@unredEmails</span>
     }

    }
 </a>

 // HERE I AM SHOWING UNREAD MESSAGES AS DROPDOWN (that HTML that is disaplyed when it's clicked on letter) AND I AM PLANING TO MOVE THIS CODE TO A PARTIAL VIEW SO THIS PART MIGHT LOOK LIKE THIS :  `@Html.Partial("_TopNavEmails");`

  <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list" role="menu">

    int unredEmails = EmailController.GetNumberOfUnreadEmails(LoggedInUser.Id);
    if (unredEmails > 0)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < unredEmails; i++)
       {
         <li>
            <a>
              <span class="image"><img src="/myresources/images/john.png"></span>
                <span>
                    <span>John Doe</span>
                     <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="message">
                      Message number: @i;
                    </span>
            </a>
         </li>
        }
     }
  </ul>
```

As you can see guys on letter click I attached on click event:

```
onclick="GetAllUnreadEmails('@LogedUserId')
```

Here is definition of GetAllUnreadEmails javascript method:

```
<script>
    var GetAllUnreadEmails = function (userId) {
        if (userId) {
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAllUnreadEmails", "Email"),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                  PROBALY HERE I SHOULD SEND DATA TO PARTIAL VIEW
                },
                error: function (response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error!");
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("failure!");
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is `GetAllUnreadEmails` ActionMethod which should retrieve data back to a PartialView from my controller:

```
public ActionResult GetAllUnreadEmails()
{  

    //This is global user that I can access to on view also
    if (User.Id != null)
    {
        List<Emails> resultList = EmailController.GetUnreadEmailsByUserId(User.Id);
        return PartialView(resultList);
     }
     return PartialView("Error, not found!");
}
```

I guess this part I did so far has some sense, but I am stuck here I don't know how could I on success send data to a partial view and use that data to populate my span elements, so instead of "John Doe" I would like to display real sender from database.

Any kind of help would be great for me.

Thanks guys

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer amended as comments..

You need to render the partial view in your a main parent emails view.. Something like...

Main "Emails" View

```
@model TestMVC.Controllers.EmailModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Emails</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>

        @if (Model.NoOfUnReadEmails > 0)
        {
            <span class="badge bg-orange" id="inboxunredEmails">@Model.NoOfUnReadEmails</span>
        }


        <div id="divUnReadEmails">
            @Html.Partial("_UnReadEmails")
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is this partial view that is replaced by the return content of the ajax post.
Then in the Success section of the post, replace the html content of the containing div.

```
 success: function(data) {
          $("#divUnReadEmails").html(data);
 }
```

Looking at your code... I think your partial view would contain the below.

```
@model TestMVC.Controllers.EmailModel

<ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list" role="menu">

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Emails.Count; i++)
    {
        <li>
            <a>
                <span class="image"><img src="/myresources/images/john.png"></span>
                <span>
                    <span>@Model.Emails[i].EmailFor</span>
                    <span class="time">@Model.Emails[i].NoOfMinsAgoSent mins ago</span>
                </span>
                <span class="message">
                    Message number: @i;
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

In your controller, return the main Emails View with the initial data you need.

```
 public ActionResult Emails()
    {
        var emailModel = new EmailModel();
        var emailService = new EmailService();

        emailModel.NoOfUnReadEmails = emailService.GetNoOfUnreadEmails("User1") //Your count!
        emailModel.Username = "User!"; //Logged on user

        return View("Emails", emailModel);
    }
```

Then you can return the partial view for the given user.

```
    public PartialViewResult UnReadEmails(EmailModel model)
    {
        var newEmailModel = new EmailModel();
        var emailService = new EmailService();
        newEmailModel.Emails = emailService.GetUnReadEmails(model.Username);

        return PartialView("_UnReadEmails", newEmailModel);
    }
```

This should be enough to get you going..

Comment: can you take a look on my code and tell me what represent this #divUnReadEmails in my code?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro - I've amended the answer. However, you shouldn't be accessing the database inside your view. if this is MVC your view should be operating off a model that contains the email info when the view is rendered.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro - Hi.. I changed my answer to show you how I would approach this problem. There is a Parent view which contains the partial view along with the structure for you controller and email service for populating the view models upon which the view renders..

Comment: following your approach I DON'T need success: function(data) {
          $("#divUnReadEmails").html(data);
 } ?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro - Correct. But I wasn't sure how your UI was supposed to operate. Yes, get all the unread emails up front. You don't actually need the partial view unless you can change user? But given its the logged on user then i guess not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ajax best way to do it is so:
First you need to change the GetAllUnreadEmails method from controller to:

```
public JsonResult GetAllUnreadEmails()
{  

    //This is global user that I can access to on view also
    if (User.Id != null)
    {
        List<Emails> resultList = EmailController.GetUnreadEmailsByUserId(User.Id);
        return Json(resultList);
     }
     return Json(false);
}
```

and the ajax call to:

```
//if the user id is global then there is no need to send it via ajax
    <script>
        var GetAllUnreadEmails = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllUnreadEmails", "Email")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                       $('#menu1').html(' ') //to clear the contect
                       $.each(data, function () {
                           $('#menu1').append("<p>"+this.Name + " " + this.Email+"<p>")
                      })
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("error!");
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("failure!");
                    }
                });

        }
    </script>
```